# What commandline parameter to get pdf

Tags: macros

I start latex via the commandline with `latex filename`.
What do I have to do to get a pdf instead of a dvi?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`pdflatex filename`

Answer (score 6):

If you have to pass a switch for some strange reason, `latex -fmt pdflatex filename` should do the same thing as `pdflatex filename`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, there's also `latex -output-format pdf` and `latex &pdflatex file.tex`, where the ampersand might need escaping according to your shell, or having %&pdflatex as the first line of your input file. OK, did we get them all?

Comment: +1 tradition: I haven't seen `&format` in a while.  This has to occur after all switches.

Comment: How about `latex '\pdfoutput=1 \input file'`?

Comment: @Lev Bishop: good one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run `latex file.tex` and then do a `dvipdf file.dvi` on the resulting dvi file.